# Best way to make a video merging mobile app

Tags: android, ios, video, ffmpeg, xamarin

I am looking to make a mobile app that will allow the users to take X number of videos and it will combine them together to make a single video. Users will also be able to choose what to put in between each video recording and background music.

I have more experience with Xamarin/C# than with native Java/Obj-C but the only method I have found online that might accomplish this would be with using native with FFMPEG. Is this the case? Is FFMPEG even going to work for this? Is there a way to use Xamarin to accomplish what I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the AVMutableComposition and its related classes.

There's an example here, about halfway down the page: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

It looks like it's covered by Xamarin: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AMonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVMutableComposition

Comment: This would only work with IOS correct? I would still need to use FFMPEG for Android.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the tags. You're correct it will only work on iOS.